# How to provide authorization for a Laravel App to charge customer from services and products availed (NOT SUBSCRIPTION OR RECURRING)

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I just want to ask how to implement this process in my Laravel 7 app.

1. On a logged user, he will setup his payment method using Paypal account (some redirection to Paypal page)
2. After success registration/setup of Paypal account, the app can now charge customer with service/products he availed.

This is not a subscription or recurring payments.

I'm reading the Paypal API Docs but I don't know where should I focus since I don't know the real Paypal Terminology for that kind of process.

NOTE: I already implement this kind of process but on Stripe only where the customer setup his Card or Bank Account then the app can charge the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PayPal this used to be known as "Reference Transactions with Billing Agreements", and in very new integrations it's called Vault (v2 REST API vault, not the old v1 REST Vault which is of no use)

This functionality is only available if PayPal turns in on for your production account, so you need to contact PayPal about it, specifically the *business* side of PayPal via https://www.paypal.com/smarthelp/contact-us (not the MTS technical support, they don't enable new features)

If reference transactions *does* get enabled and approved for your live/production business account (no guarantee of this), then PayPal will guide you on which specific API to use, which could be the newest v2 Vault or something else.

Comment: Thanks for response. I read about it and it says we must communicate to Paypal for this or just use Braintree. source: [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payment-tokens/#]

Comment: That page is all about the v1 vault which as I mentioned is of no use. You need reference transactions, which yes you do need to contact PayPal about first. Braintree is a different PayPal service, but would be another option